# Framework para Windows forms ou WPF

Tags: c#, winforms, wpf

Galera, gostaria de saber se existe algum framework para Windows forms ou WPF, para facilitar o desenvolvimento.
 framework que facilitasse a criação das UI, e acesso a dados .

Comment: Bom, você tem alguns helpers, Telerik, DevExpress, esses te ajudam mais com a interface, um framework para manipulação de dados, um ORM por exemplo, existe o Entity Framework, acredito que precisa ser mais específico no seu problema para que alguém possa te ajudar, a sua pergunta é muito abrangente, precisa expor um problema mais específico.

Answer (score 1):

Confira o [Rocket Framework - Windows Form](http://rocketframework.codeplex.com/)

- Ele usa o Entity Framework como o back-end;
- Permite um vínculo automático da fonte de dados com a interface;
- Use Generic para minimizar a programação;
- Uma ampla documentação e atualmente está estável;

Eu conheci esse FrameWork através da pergunta:
[Is there any framework for Windows Forms, DB driven application development/prototyping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457365/is-there-any-framework-for-windows-forms-db-driven-application-development-prot)